# How to add my own "help" information to a python function/class?

Tags: python, documentation

I know I can use "help()" to see existing help information from packages. But after I wrote my own function/class, how can I enable "help" to see help document? I know the first line of "comment" is a **doc** attribute, but that's not what I wanted.

I wish to have my own package compiled, and others could see from "help()". How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`help()` is entirely based on `__doc__` attributes (and introspection of function arguments), so make sure your module, your classes and your functions all have a docstring.

A docstring is *not* a comment, it is a bare string literal right at the top:

```
"""This is a module docstring, shown when you use help() on a module"""

class Foo:
    """Help for the class Foo"""

    def bar(self):
        """Help for the bar method of Foo classes"""

def spam(f):
    """Help for the spam function"""
```

For example, the popular third-party `requests` module has a docstring:

```
>>> import requests
>>> requests.__doc__
'\nRequests HTTP library\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n\nRequests is an HTTP library, written in Python, for human beings. Basic GET\nusage:\n\n   >>> import requests\n   >>> r = requests.get(\'https://www.python.org\')\n   >>> r.status_code\n   200\n   >>> \'Python is a programming language\' in r.content\n   True\n\n... or POST:\n\n   >>> payload = dict(key1=\'value1\', key2=\'value2\')\n   >>> r = requests.post(\'http://httpbin.org/post\', data=payload)\n   >>> print(r.text)\n   {\n     ...\n     "form": {\n       "key2": "value2",\n       "key1": "value1"\n     },\n     ...\n   }\n\nThe other HTTP methods are supported - see `requests.api`. Full documentation\nis at <http://python-requests.org>.\n\n:copyright: (c) 2016 by Kenneth Reitz.\n:license: Apache 2.0, see LICENSE for more details.\n'
```

which is rendered by `help()` directly, together with the module contents (and recursively, the content docstrings):

```
>>> help('requests')
Help on package requests:

NAME
    requests

DESCRIPTION
    Requests HTTP library
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    Requests is an HTTP library, written in Python, for human beings. Basic GET
    usage:

       >>> import requests
       >>> r = requests.get('https://www.python.org')
       >>> r.status_code
       200
[...]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use argparse: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html.  It allows you to create a `--help` parameter that you can customize as well as add argument descriptions.

Example:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "Write your help documentation here...")
parser.add_argument('config.txt', nargs='?', help='Write about your positional arguments here')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

So when someone runs your program with `--help` it will output:

```
$python yourProgram.py --help
usage: yourProgram.py [-h] [config.txt]

Write your help documentation here...

positional arguments:
config.txt  Write about your positional arguments here

optional arguments:
-h, --help  show this help message and exit
```